# Chrome source tab shows .less files which are not in my solution

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to use less.js and after installing it I see some extra .less files (e.g. 
alert.less, badges.less etc) which are not on my hard drive and are conflicting with my css styles. Where are they coming from ? I would like to use less but keeping my css intact.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are part of bootstrap. See here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: Why are these needed when I'm using a bootstrap.css ?
Is it related to the fact that I installed a less.js package to my solution ? Cause new solution just show bootstrap css files and .less files are not showing up.

Comment: Same question here. Link in answer is outdated. Could you refer to a topic or similar?